# na not picking missing values?

Tags: python, pandas, imputation

Have a DF med562. A categorical variable has distribution below

```
I    6119923

O     764905

      166666

Name: IND, dtype: int64
```

Want to just impute the 166666 missing values using value of I, the one with 6119923 rows. Wrote this

```
med562['IND']=med562['IND'].fillna(value='I')

Catcounts=med562.IND.value_counts(dropna=False)

Catcounts
```

It did not change, still the same distribution. This is running on Python 3.7.3. Should not be software issue. Any thought? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not `NaN`, it is whitespace , if that is `NaN` when you do `value_counts` it will not show in the result , since `dropna=True` in `value_counts` defaulted as True

```
med562['IND']=med562['IND'].replace({'':'I'})

Catcounts=med562.IND.value_counts(dropna=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, only if there is no space between ' '. How do we detect how many whitespaces are in the original data, though? In this case, I first, habitually had a space between '' like ' '. It did not work. So I squeezed out any space in between. It works. Thanks. This really helps.

Comment: @opt135 `med562['IND'].str.strip().replace({'':'I'})`

Comment: See. str.strip() condenses whatever is in-between ' ' to fit the later [{'',]

Comment: @opt135 yep , however , is this what you need ?